# identify the input that is multiple of 11 and odd or even java

Tags: java

@oldrinb and @iccthedral Thanks, But i should use printf or println. I edited this way but same as before

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class test
{
    public static void main( String args[] )
    {
        Scanner input = new Scanner( System.in );
        int x;
        int EO;
        int Mult;
        System.out.print ( "Enter value: " );
        x = input.nextInt();
        EO=x%2;
            Mult=x%11;
            if(EO>0&&Mult>0)
            {
                System.out.printf ("%d:NOT:ODD\n",x);
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: The above looks like java, so which is it?  Java is **not** the same as javascript.

Comment: Just check to see if the number is a multiple of `22`. If it's divisible by both `2` and `11`, it has to be divisible by `2 * 11`.

Comment: Don't label Java questions as "javascript".  It wastes the readers' time.  http://kb.mozillazine.org/JavaScript_is_not_Java, http://www.456bereastreet.com/archive/200909/java_is_not_javascript/

Comment: @BolorCh `EO > 0` means odd and `Mult > 0` means non-multiple of 11.

Comment: Also, if the program displays a stack trace when you run it (which it does for most odd numbers!!) then you will get a better answer if you include the stacktrace in your question.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, it needs to be tagged as such.

Comment: @javamonkey79 - Nope - the moderators will detag it on sight.

Comment: @StephenC - really? I missed that policy update apparently. When did that happen?

Comment: @javamonkey79 - http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/trogdor-ate-my-homework-tag

Answer (score 2):

> but when I entered my value it did not displays the result. as "input:NOT:ODD"

Nothing got displayed?

Correct me if I'm wrong in assuming things here, but this...

`System.out.printf ("%d:NOT:ODD", );`

should instead be

`System.out.printf ("%d:NOT:ODD\n", x);`

P.S
 One thing to note is @Blender's  suggestion.

Comment: yeah, I tried this way, also nothing displayed. In the programm i should write 4 times of if statement. I just want to see the result from the beginning and then will proceed with this. But nothing displayed again. 4 if should be like 1. Multiple and Even, 2. Not Multiple and even, 3. Multiple and odd, 4. not Multuple and odd. If i use multiple of 22, I will use 2 if's.

Comment: Then would you please care explaining in exact, concise manner, what you're trying to achieve. Say, give us an example of the expected output for given example input.

Comment: @BolorCh print `\n` or call `System.out.flush()`

Comment: oldrinb - Thank you, I initially wanted to append `\n` but I didn't for some reason. @BolorCh Would you try it now?

Answer (score 0):

You have to enter in a number that satisfies both of the conditions in your if statement. So if you were to enter 11 or 22 than it wouldn't print anything.